# Searching across multiple indices and serializing multiple document types with django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following setup:

```
Django 3.0.7
Elasticsearch 7.7
django-elasticsearch-dsl
django-elasticsearch-drf
```

So far I have created 4 different document types and serializers and also 4 different search endpoints.

I have not been able to figure out how to create one endpoint for returning serialized search results from all 4 indices. The serialized search results are all slightly different with different custom fields.

While the endpoints work fine I am not sure how to handle the search without making 4 requests on the front-end each time a search request is submitted. I would also like the results to be paginated so having 4 endpoints is most likely not going to work.

Does anyone have experience with a similar scenario?

Comment: If the fields that are used / not used are `keyword` types you could add a [`constant_keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/constant-keyword.html) type for each field to make each index mapping have the same fields as each other?  Otherwise you could try writing and parsing your own queries JSON manually to achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution? Looking for this kind of approach rn